# How to get item in WebMethod using Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I have created one WebMethod, In this method I want to access item from path.

```cs
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static int ItemCount()
{
     int val = 0;
     Item itm = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("Id will be there");
     val = itm.Children.Count;
     return val;
}
```

but I am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Can anyone suggest me how I can use it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object reference` exception can happen in your code only when `GetItem` method returned null.

3 things you need to check are:

1. What is the `Sitecore.Context.Database` when you execute the code? `web`, `master`, or maybe `core`?
2. What is the id you passed to your method? Is this the valid id you wanted to pass?
3. Does item with this id exist in the database (e.g. is it published to `web` database)?

Comment: Same function is working when i use without WebMethod

Comment: When you use WebMethod, Sitecore can resolve its context in a different way. That's why `Sitecore.Context.Database` can be different.